# Does sculpt mode support any way for a mesh to deform itself upon contact?

Tags: rigging, sculpting, soft-body

So I had a teddy bear in the works: 
[image]
but the problem is that the leg should interfere with the body when it is moved.  I was using the pose brush (but have no opposition to a rig.)
What would you guys suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, I don’t think sculpt mode brushing can be animated. My first thought was to use cloth body physics with self collision enabled, but this may not provide what you’re looking for. You would be able to animate that, though, and even pin parts of the mesh to an armature to pose it.

Comment: I think you can use shape keys when sculpting; that could be used for animation, right?

Comment: yes, you can do that. I hadn’t thought of that. However, you would need one shape key for every position the various parts of the mesh could be in. One for when the right arm is up, one for when it is down, one for when the left arm is up, one for when it is down, etc. Thankfully, you would not need a shape key for say when the right arm is up and the left one is down, and other combination poses, as long as they do not contain the same vertices.